# Can someone give an example of a function that is not Henstock-Kurzweil/gauge integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, examples-counterexamples, gauge-integral

I am looking for an example of a function that is not Henstock-Kurzweil integrable. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I do not know the answer, but I feel like a function that has something to do with a non Lebesgue measurable set would do. Since Lebesgue integral is "absolute convergent" and gauge integral is "conditional convergent"; the power of gauge integral is to integrate highly oscillating functions.

Comment: How about $1/x$, say on $(-1,1)$ ?

Comment: $1/x$ is Riemann integrable, so it is also Henstock-Kurzweil integrable, right?

Comment: No, a function must be bounded to be Riemann integrable, but I believe your second statement is true.

Comment: Of course, it would be easy to come up with an unbounded functions that the integral sum is positive infinity. The goal would be finding a bounded function on $[a,b]$ that is not Henstock-Kurzweil integrable.

Comment: @TedShifrin $1/x$ is not Henstock-Kurzweil integrable

Comment: @Xiao: any bounded measurable function on a bounded interval is Lebesgue-integrable, and therefore also Henstock-Kurzweil integrable (I believe that HK-integrable functions are measurable, but don't know/remember why)

Comment: @user8268: I should have kept my mouth shut, since I hadn't even heard of Henstock-Kurzweil integrals a week ago. :) Apologies. I'll stick to Riemann and Lebesgue. :)

Answer (score 3):

Take any infinite series $a$, and let $f(x)$ be $a_{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}$ (where $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ is the greatest integer that is not greater than $x$, that is $x$ rounded down to an integer).  In general, $$ \int_i^j f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n = i}^{j-1} a_n ,$$ whenever $i$ and $j$ are integers.  As stated, this is a fine Riemann integral, but change $j$ to $\infty$ and we have:

- $ \int_i^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n = i}^\infty a_n $ as a Lebesgue integral iff $a$ is absolutely convergent;
- $ \int_i^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n = i}^\infty a_n $ as an improper Riemann integral iff $a$ is convergent (possibly conditionally);
- $ \int_i^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n = i}^\infty a_n $ also as a Henstock–Kurzweil integral iff $a$ is convergent (possibly conditionally).

So any divergent series gives a Henstock–Kurzweil nonintegrable function.  The harmonic series, for example, gives $f(x) = 1/\lfloor{x}\rfloor$, which is not integrable.

OK, so just plain $1/x$ is an even simpler nonintegrable function, but I think that if you keep in mind the relationship between Lebesgue vs Henstock and absolute vs conditional convergence, then it will seem more obvious to you that, while Henstock–Kurzweil makes *more* functions integrable, it does not make *all* functions integrable.

Comment: For some people, Henstock–Kurzweil integrals are only defined on bounded intervals.  Then the spirit of this answer does not work, although 1/x still works, only now the issue is near 0 rather than near infinity.  But I don't deserve credit for that answer; @user8268 already gave it in the comments to the question.

Comment: If you want, instead of $[0, \infty)$ you can consider $[0, 1]$ and define $f$ to be equal to $2^na_n$ on $[1-2^n, 1-2^{n+1})$ and $f(1) = 0$. This will give the same result but on a compact interval.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem. If function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Henstock-Kurzweil integrable, then $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function.

You can find proof of the above theorem in "The integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock" by Russel Gordon (Theorem 9.12).

Thus a characteristic function of a non-measurable set would be an example you are looking for.